# Adding member to MailChimp with API not showing in the web gui before i add more

Tags: mailchimp

I using the API v3 and createing a list and then adding a member to it, then i going to the web gui https://usxx.admin.mailchimp.com/lists/ and there i dont see the member.

When i then createing a list with a new member the first member shows up in the first list and the new list shows up but no member in the web gui.

I have tried adding two members at the same time but still not showing up any of them, looks like when i adding list number 2 its shows up, some ideas?

Edit: Now after left it and waiting for answer here i reloaded the page with lists and then i got the member for the last list. Is there some delay?

Comment: i am also observing this delay

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm that as of this writing MailChimp seems to have a delay. Somewhere between 2 and 5 minutes after adding people to a list - they show up on the UX.

This said I've observed in my tests that the API seems to have updates immediately. My guess is that their UX caches results for a short duration.